# Adword api to access keyword volume from a url

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

I'm new to Adwords Api i have setup all the account and have all the credentials need to make a api call.

i have developerToken, clientCustomerId, ClientId, ClientSecret but the api lib is too complicated for me (PHP lib). Is there a way to get data in JSON format like we do for other calls 
like I'm using below Url to get result if website is mobile friendly or not

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?key='.$apiKey.'&url='.$url.'&strategy=mobile
```

Is there any way to do something like this for keyword search volume ?

Comment: what you mean with  _keyword search volume_?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you need to get the search volume for each keyword. You can refer this documents,

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/targeting-idea-service

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/traffic-estimator-service

I hope these would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks For replying but i cant find a good guide on setting adword api can you share a good link as google doc is not helping out

Comment: @manishSingh Follow their official documentation, 

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start

The code samples,

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/samples-use-cases